# Comma inside a Json Array( Getting this value , set a value using the json path)

Tags: arrays, json, jsonpath, rest-assured-jsonpath, json-path-expression

```
"Message": {
        "Heading": {
            "ABC": {
                "sample": [
                    "465783",
                    "647837"
                ],
                
            }
        },
```

`I have this json sample to read and update the values using the json path , tried different ways of writing the path but none worked for me`

`**Requirement** : Need to get the value of sample and also to update the two values in it using the json path , my trails are below

1. Message.Heading.ABC.sample
   2. Message.Heading.ABC.sample
   [0] or Message.Heading.ABC.sample[1]
   3. Message.Heading.ABC.sample.[0] or Message.Heading.ABC.sample.[1]`